# Is there an Ability Modifier equation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores

Is there an equation to determine the Ability Modifier?

I'm not talking about the chart that lists

- 1 = −5
- 2-3 = −4
- 4-5 = −3
- 6-7 = −2
- etc.

I mean a legit equation that, if I somehow misplaced this information, I could determine what the modifier is based on the score?

Answer (score 61):

The formula is simply:

$$ 
\frac{\mathrm{ability} - 10}{2}
$$

with the result rounded down, if it contains any halves.

Answer (score 39):

I know this is old but I think the current answers are close but slightly inadequate. I think the formula itself (rather than comments/descriptions) needs to account for rounding somehow, so here is an actual formula (in Google Sheets or Microsoft Excel syntax) that does work, and I feel is human-readable:

```
=(ROUNDDOWN(A1/2) - 5)
```

Where A1 is the ability score (or cell).

You could also use truncation, e.g. `TRUNC(A1/2,0)-5`, casting, e.g. `INT(A1/2)-5`, or the floor function, e.g. `FLOOR(A1/2)-5` to effectively turn the decimals into integers. I feel like `ROUNDDOWN` is a bit more self-explanatory.

Mathematically, the above formula would be expressed using the floor function notation:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{a}{2}\right\rfloor - 5$$

Where \$a\$ is the ability score.

Comment: I am amused that your formula is nearly identical to my original post. +1, and I am curious if readers will like it more than my current answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple if you do a different equation like this:

$$\left(\frac{\text{score}}{2}\right) - 5=\text{Modifier}$$

Comment: This doesn't quite work either; you still need some sort of situational rounding or truncation.

Comment: -1, because as Josh mentions it doesn't perfectly capture what is needed to calculate the answer, and otherwise doesn't say anything my answer didn't already.

Answer (score 1):

## The Euclidean quotient of Ability divided by 2, remainder discarded, minus 5

Euclidean division is the process of dividing two integers to produce an integer quotient and an integer remainder. For example, 11 **div** 2 yields a quotient of 5 and a remainder of 1, where **div** signifies Euclidean division.

Comment: Similar answers have been stated previously using a variety of descriptions of the division required or processing of the quotient after real number division. Perhaps this is the rigorous answer sought?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's already been stated, but the method I use is round the base number down to the nearest even (17->16) divide by half (16/2 = 8) and then subtract 5 (8-5=3)