# How to calculate strength over 30?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

My enlarged mutant orc barbarian in rage has strength 34.

How to calculate strength modifier over 30?

Hmm.

Comment: Covered in http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71076/is-there-an-ability-modifier-equation

Answer (score -3):

All that you have to do is go the d20pfsrd.com page and look at the table.

Ability Modifier and Bonus Spells table on the [Ability Scores](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores) page

Comment: Thank you. That's all I wanted to know. See the table. There's max 30.

Comment: If you'll notice. In the tables Everytime the stat goes up by two, the modifier goes up by one. Changing at every even number.

Comment: @CarlosSatyros: The maximum is not 30. There *is* no formal maximum.

Comment: Good to know. There's is no 31 in table. That was the question. I know the answer. Thank you all